# Access In App Purchase Plugin in Ionic 2

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

I am making a small Ionic 2 app for learning the framework and want to test the in app purchase plugin (cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inapppurchase).

My plugin list is

```
$ ionic plugins list
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.3 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-inapppurchase 1.0.0 "In App Purchase"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

So it seams like the plugin is installed correctly.

I've read I could access Cordova plugins via

```
cordova.plugins.myPlugin.aFunction()
```

In my controller I coded the following to print my accessible plugins:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    console.log(cordova.plugins);
 });
```

When I deploy the app on my Android device It just holds the Keyboard-function. 
Do you have an idea how I could use and access the In App Purchase plugin? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried but just came across something that may be helpful yesterday.

[You must create a manifest.json in your project's www folder with your Android Billing Key:](https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase#android)